# How to add swipe gesture for uilabel inside tableview in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to creating check list in a table view. Inside table view radio button and UILabel, here adding swipe gesture to UILabel. For single swipe of UILabel will show radio button or double swipe of UILabel will show dash line.

I have tried of adding gesture to UILabel inside table by using selector method, it print successfully but UILabel is not swiping.

Here is the code tried of swiping UILabel:

In viewDidLoad:

```
let gestureRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(sender:)))
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRec)
    gestureRec.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

And created function called didTap:

```
     @objc func didTap(sender : UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
      {
      if sender.state == .ended {
        let location = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
        var cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! textCell
        print("swipe")
        cell.labelView.frame(forAlignmentRect: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: 20, 
     height: 15))

    }
   }
```

Comment: It seems like you are after the same functionality as when you are deleting a message (i.e. when a user swipes, the cell moves and shows additional options). If that is what you are after, then you need to look into `UITableView`'s methods such as `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` & `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this code. Tested and working fine 100 %**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableDataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelSwipedLeft(sender:)))
    cell.textLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    return cell

@objc func labelSwipedLeft(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("labelSwipedLeft called")
  }
```

**See the output**
[image]

---

**Additional**: If you want to detect which row's label was tapped, then assign a tag to the label in cellForRowAt like

```
cell.textLabel?.tag = indexPath.row
```

And get the row index in the function **labelSwipedLeft** using

```
print("labelSwipedLeft called for row \(sender.view!.tag)")
```

Comment: @objc func swipedToLeft(sender : UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if sender.state == .ended {
            let location = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
            var cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! textCell
            print("swipe")
//            cell.labelView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//
            cell.labelView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: 20, height: 30)
            
        }
    }
Is this correct??????

Comment: @BizDev I don't think that label should move. This code is for recognizing a gesture. We have to move the label using some sort of animation i guess

Comment: Thanks right now the label is moving. how to do double swipe ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169135/discussion-between-awais-fayyaz-and-bizdev).

Comment: To use left swipe only, specify `swipeLeft.direction = .left` else it will work for left and right

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I noticed is that you are adding the gesture on `UITableView` and not `UILabel`. **So you need to fix that first.**
Secondly, for a gesture to work correctly on a control, **you must enable the user interaction property of that control**, else it won't respond to the gesture. So :

```
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

You can add the gesture as follows :

```
let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipedToLeft))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
label.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitish how add gesture to uilabel??

Comment: Same as you are doing for UITableView

Comment: do you want  add it in viewdidload let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipedToLeft))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
label.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

Comment: here label is in tableview cell label.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

Comment: It has to be in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Nitish how to move UIlabel to right while swiping. It prints successfully

Comment: Is this correct ???          @objc func swipedToLeft(sender : UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if sender.state == .ended {
            let location = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
            var cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! textCell
            print("swipe")
//            cell.labelView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//
            cell.labelView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: 20, height: 30)
            
        }
    }

Comment: @objc func labelSwipe(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { print("labelSwipedLeft called") }

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding swipe gesture in cell class, rather than `ViewController`.

```
func setupGestures() {
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLeftSwipe(_:)))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    label.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func handleLeftSwipe(_ recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

call `setupGestures` in `awakeFromNib`.
Also if you want to drag the label, use pan gesture

Comment: This is a good suggestion, which I tried, but if you also use `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:` or `trailing....`, then your code won't be executed.